# Fulfilling POST to DB from Razor MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have never done a POST request via Razor and MVC4.  I think i have the core methods and stuff down but i am having difficulty fulfilling an actual POST request.

Here is the Razor View page code...

```
@model UserJob
@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.UserCode)
@Html.DropDownList("jobCode")
<input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />
```

And the method which i want to fulfil the POST method is.....

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSkill(UserJob model)
{
    db.UserJobs.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Jobs", new { UserCode = model.UserCode });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Razor view needs to have the form. Either use `@Html.BeginForm(...)` to enclose your inputs, or just write HTML form markup yourself.